# Looking for a clean way to handle errors in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm learning RxJava and I have seen in many places that an error can be handled this way:

```
repository.getById(10).subscribe(new Action1<User>() {
            @Override
            public void call(User user) {
              //Do something
            }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof FirstErrorException) {
                    handleFirstError((FirstErrorException) t);
                } else if (t instanceof FirstErrorException) {
                    handleSecondError((SecondErrorException) t);
                } else {
                    //and so on... 
                }
            }
        });
```

Am I the only one that thinks that this is really bad code? How can I make it better? I though using `Visitor` pattern that "visits" each concrete type of my base exception, but `onError` method always requires an `Action1<Throwable>`; you can't use your own base exception, just `Throwable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error handlers to the rescue:

```
 <T,E extends Throwable> Observable<T>
 whenExceptionIs(Class<E> what, Func1<E,Observable<T>> result) {
     return t -> {
        return what.isInstance(t) ? result.call(t) : Observable.error(t);
     };
 }
```

This you use like this:

```
Observable<Foo> obs = ...
    .onErrorResumeNext(whenExceptionIs(IllegalArgumentException.class, t-> Observable.just(Foo.newInstance())))
    .onErrorResumeNext(whenExceptionIs(IOException.class, t-> Observable.error(new XyzzyException("",t))))
 ....
```

Comment: Where would I put that error handler (whenExceptionIs) so it is available to the code globally?  In its own class as a static method?

Comment: Yep; I have a class full of them with reasonable names.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Is the host class static too, or just the method names?  For example: public class utility { public static <T,E extends Throwable> Observable<T> whenExceptionIs(... }  I don't see "public static" in front of your whenExceptionIs() declaration so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error message when I try to build a class using that error handler.  I made a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106144/intellij-showing-compiler-errors-on-rxjava-error-handler-method-that-uses-isinst

Comment: god, I really just can't understand generics transformations to build such a function! because this in it's clear form doesn't gonna work (return type is observable, but inside a lambda is described). if someone can just to write a real working example for such a thing here - please, do :)

Comment: I built jut this
`private <E extends Throwable, T> Single<T>
    whatInstanceIsAsSingle(Class<E> what, Function<E, Single<T>> function, Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        return what.isInstance(throwable)
                ? function.apply((E) throwable)
                : Single.error(throwable);
    }`

but I don't feel that is implemented right