# RxJava - Wait for Observable to complete

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have two `Observable` sequences namely `Observable1` and `Observable2`. They both are executed on separated schedulers.

`Observable1` fetches data from the database whereas `Observable2` fetches the same data from the server.

The result of these two `Observable`sequences is sent to the `Observer` using a subject.

Now if there is no internet connectivity, then `Observable2` executes `onError()` before `Observable1` could post its `onNext()` event.

How to wait for `Observable1` to emit its `onNext()` event before `Observable2` starts emitting?

Here's some code:

`Observable1 = dataRepo.getItems().doOnNext({
serializedSubject.onNext(items)}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());`

`Observable2 = cloudRepo.getItems().doOnNext({
dataRepo.addAll(items)
dataRepo.getItems().subscribe(serializedSubject)}).
subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());`

`Observable.mergeDelayError(Observable1, Observable2)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Subscriber());`

Comment: Have you tried using the merge operator.http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: Thank you @blackpanther. I think I can get it working using mergeDelayError operator. Will try it :)

Comment: merge with delay still emits onError before onNext. :( Posted some sample code for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you just don't care about error codes, add `.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())` at the end of each Observable; you'll just need the normal `merge` operator.

Comment: Thank you Tassos for your help but I need to handle the error after I get onNext. Is there a way to catch a specific exception like an UnknownHostException? I tried onExceptionResumeNext but that handles all exceptions :(

Comment: Found it. Can pass a function to OnErrorResumeNext and check the type of throwable instance that is passed into the function.

Comment: Sure. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043561/looking-for-a-clean-way-to-handle-errors-in-rxjava/39050943#39050943