# Only catch exceptions of a specific type in RxJava 2

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm just learning RxJava 2 and I would like catch exceptions only of a specific type and return an Observable.  Essentially, I want `onErrorResumeNext()` to only catch a specific exception class, but it looks like she doesn't work that way.

What are my options for achieving this behavior in RxJava 2?  Just use `onErrorResumeNext()`, handle my specific exception and rethrow the others?  Something like:

```
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> throwable instanceof NotFoundException ? Observable.empty() : Observable.error(throwable));
```

Comment: Yes, the `Function` variant of `onErrorResumeNext` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, @akarnokd.  

I'm trying to understand why `onErrorResumeNext` has the signature:

`onErrorResumeNext(Function<? super Throwable, ...>)`

It would seem to me that  `? extends Throwable` is what we want rather than `? super Throwable`.  This would allow
`.onErrorResumeNext((NotNullException throwable) -> ...` which makes sense to me, rather than `.onErrorResumeNext((Object throwable) -> ...` which does not.

Comment: Java's type system is not powerful enough to express such type capture through lambda.

Answer (score 7):

I would return Observable.empty instead just null

```
.onErrorResumeNext(t -> t instanceof NullPointerException ? Observable.empty():Observable.error(t))
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use composition:

```
public <T> Function<Throwable, Observable<T>> whenExceptionIsThenIgnore(Class<E> what) {
  return t -> {
    return what.isInstance(t) ? Observable.empty() : Observable.error(t);
  };
}
```

Then use like this:

```
Observable.from(...).flatMap(...)
.onErrorResumeNext(whenExceptionIsThenIgnore(IllegalArgumentException.class))
.onErrorResumeNext(whenExceptionIsThenIgnore(IOException.class))
...
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043561/looking-for-a-clean-way-to-handle-errors-in-rxjava/39050943#39050943) on selectively handling exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

if you need global error handling, you can use `RxJavaPlugins`

```
RxJavaPlugins.setOnObservableAssembly(observable -> {
        if (observable instanceof ObservableError){
            return observable.doOnError(throwable -> {
                if(throwable instanceof SpecificException){
                    handleSpecificException();
                }
            });
        }
        return observable;
    });
```

(Similar approach can be used for Singles, Maybes or Completables)